# jQuery .toggleClass() transition

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, toggleclass

im writing a jQuery Script that changes the opacity of an img on hover using `.toggleClass()` the css of the class is:

```
.img-hover{
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

it issue is when I remove my mouse I want it to transition back to the original opacity, but it happens suddenly because of the toggle class, my code is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".port-item-img").hover(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('img-hover');
    });
});
```

any ideas?

I am aware this can all be done with css on its own but i'm trying to push myself to learn new things with jQuery as I'm quite new to it and like a challenge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution with only jQuery (without additional CSS styles).

[.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) provides element's animation, and [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) is used to stop current animation (if it is still in process) before adding new animation.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p53ew9cy/1/).

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".port-item-img").hover
    (
        function()
        {
            $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 0.5 }, 1000);
        },
        function()
        {
            $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 1 }, 1000);
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: AWESOME! dont even need the css, ive only been using jQeury for a couple of days and good im loving its abilities!

Comment: @ShoutItWebSolutions you're welcome. Using CSS3 instead of JS is sometimes more appropriate way (works faster and so on), but if you want something very custom, here comes JS and jQuery. And yes: jQuery has very good abilities :)

Answer (score 1):

To make it slow you should make:

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".port-item-img").hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('img-hover');
        $(this).removeClass('img-unhover');

    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('img-hover');
        $(this).addClass('img-unhover');

    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.img-unhover{
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that when the class is removed the `transition` attribute also is lost

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".port-item-img").hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('img-hover');
  });
});
```

```css
.img-hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.port-item-img {
  transition: opacity 3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="port-item-img">port-item-img</div>
<div class="port-item-img">port-item-img</div>
<div class="port-item-img">port-item-img</div>
```